# Aligning lines of text while \raggedleft

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

Here is an example of the desired effect (hrule to show margins of the page):
[image]

As shown in the picture, the text consists of two columns - each line in the left column ends together while each line in the right column begins together. The text is also moved to the right margin of the page through \raggedleft.

I would like to have code that aligns them as such without the need of `\hspace` whenever the content of the text is changed.

Here is the code I used for the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\hrule
\medskip
\hspace{154.5mm} \emph{Money} \$100 \par
\hspace{165.85mm} \$1000 \par
\hspace{165.85mm} \$10000 \par
\raggedleft \$100000
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\hrule
\medskip

\begin{flushright}
\emph{Money} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\$}l@{}}
100\\
1000\\
10000\\
100000  
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```